# iOS statusBar not display in iphonex when full screen

Tags: ios

I already set this. it can work in other devices except iphoneX when full screen. Can anyone help?

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

   return NO;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by full screen ?

Comment: its the default feature in iphone-X we can't handle

Comment: Your app is in landscape mode if yes then it will not be display because of default features

Comment: Thanks for your reminding.